# Maven plugin resolution message

Tags: maven

To check project plugin status I ran :

`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`

Output was

```
...
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: commons-lang-2.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: commons-io-1.4.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.jar
...
```

what is the difference between the message lines. Ideally I would expect `Plugin Dependency Resolved` so what does the other message mean ?

Comment: One is a dependency of a plugin, the other _is_ the plugin. What's the issue?

Comment: In eclipse I see there are lot of "omitted for conflict with *" messages wrt to dependencies or plugins. But I don't see much info when I run `mvn dependency:tree` so I was trying to understand what they mean. Is there any place where all the message meaning is listed ?